# Java assert nasty side-effect - compiler bug?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, assert

This

```
public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Object o = null;
        assert o != null;
        if(o != null)
          System.out.println("o != null");
    }
}
```

prints out "o != null"; both 1.5_22 and 1.6_18. Compiler bug? Commenting out the assert fixes it. The byte code appears to jump directly to the print statement when assertions are disabled:

```
 public static main(String[]) : void
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    ACONST_NULL
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
    GETSTATIC test.$assertionsDisabled : boolean
    IFNE L2
    ALOAD 1: o
    IFNONNULL L2
    NEW AssertionError
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL AssertionError.<init>() : void
    ATHROW
   L2
    LINENUMBER 8 L2
    GETSTATIC System.out : PrintStream
    LDC "o != null"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL PrintStream.println(String) : void
   L3
    LINENUMBER 9 L3
    RETURN
   L4
```

Comment: doesn't print anything here, 1.6.0_12

Comment: Which version of javac compiler did you use to compile? It should be a compiler bug, compiling with 1.6.0_18 (windows 32-bit) code works as expected (does not print o!= null).

Comment: Not reproducible. Are you sure that this is exactly your test code? What compiler and what jvm are you using? What flags?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 bit. Will retest x32 ...

Comment: Unless I am missing someting obvious, I am seeing this behaviour (prints out o!=null) on everything I try (win7 1.6.0_18 64 and 32 bit, and 1.5.0_22) Need to retest with SDK/command line, only tried from witin Eclipse (JREs) ...

Comment: Does not happen with jdk1.6.0_18 command line javac/java. Now I just need to figure out what's different with the way Eclipse builds it / runs it ...

Comment: Reproduced with a clean install of the latest Eclipse milestone for win 64 bit (eclipse-java-helios-M5-win32-x86_64) and 1.6.0_18 JRE. Need to test other configs and older eclipse, would have to be tommorow ...

Comment: Maybe you should clarify your question and mention that this happens with ecj (the Eclipse Compiler for Java) and not Sun's javac. BTW, it works fine with Galileo (and Java 6u18) for me.

Comment: Not reproducible in Eclipse 3.6 (32bit) on 1.6.0_21 on Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "nasty".  Can you give a real example of some code where this would bite you?  Your example looks very contrived.

**EDIT** - out of curiosity, I typed in the program, compiled it and ran it with java 1.6.0_16.  No compiler bug is evident for me:

- With assertions enabled (java -ea test) I get an assertion error.
- With assertions disabled (java test) I get *no* output.

Comment: I'd argue that any bug that makes the compiler generate code that silently does the wrong thing is "nasty". (A less nasty compiler bug would be if the compiler actually failed to compile such code -- then at least you know something is wrong.)

Comment: Thanks for testing. Just tried, does not happen with jdk1.6.0_18 for me either. Now I just need to figure out what's different with the way Eclipse builds it ...

Comment: @Alex Eclipse has its own compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Assertions can be enabled and disabled at runtime. If you execute your code with the -ea-switch (for enable assertions) the assert should work:

```
java -ea my.class
```

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is optimising the if (o != null) clause away because you've already asserted that o is never going to be null.

Assertion are not enabled by default at runtime, and are generally used to validate that code fulfils some contract, e.g. you just want to make sure that a certain object is never going to be null (e.g. to avoid null pointer exceptions). It is because of that "contract" that the compiler can optimise the if (o != null) away, because it knows that this condition will never happen.

As they are generally not enabled at runtime, think of them as helping to develop a piece of code rather than a runtime error checking mechanism.

Comment: Can you point out the section of the JLS that says that the compiler may assume assertions are true when optimizing?

Comment: Nope. Combined with the other answers that cannot replicate the behaviour and the fact I didn't try it myselve,  I'm tempted to believe that it might have been a compiler bug but some overzealous optimisation could have been the cause...

Comment: Considering that the code only appears to occur when built with the Eclipse compiler, maybe the Eclipse compiler is optimising the if statement away?